# How can I use memcached (Amazon elasticache) from both scala and rails simultaneously?

Tags: ruby, scala, amazon-web-services, memcached

I am trying to get a scala client and a rails client to talk to the same aws memcached cluster. The scala/java client I am using is [spy.memcached](https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-elasticache-cluster-client-memcached-for-java) and the ruby gem that seems to offer the best support for aws is [dalli](https://github.com/mperham/dalli). Unfortunately, given the same servers, they often store the same key on different servers.

Does anyone know of a simple way (short of rewriting the hash functions) to get these two to seamlessly interoperate?

Comment: Do you use `configuration endpoint` or `node endpoints` ?

Comment: Configuration endpoint,  but they ultimately both return a list of servers, and I checked that they are in the same order.

Comment: From scala: `scala> cl.getAvailableServers
res1: java.util.Collection[java.net.SocketAddress] = [/10.0.0.119:11211, /10.0.0.145:11211, /10.0.0.202:11211, /10.0.0.152:11211]`
From ruby: `irb(main):007:0> cl.servers
=> ["10.0.0.119:11211", "10.0.0.145:11211", "10.0.0.202:11211", "10.0.0.152:11211"]`
From scala, I call `cl.set("1", "one")` and `cl.set("2", "two")`. From ruby, only one of them shows up (e.g. `cl.get("2")` is `nil`).

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to use just one node in a cluster.

Second option: set the same key=>value to the all nodes and read from any node.

Third option(extra coding): using gem called [dalli-elasticache](https://github.com/ktheory/dalli-elasticache) for ruby on rails and implement the same algorithm of detecting node for scala. Basically you need to modify key name which would include the node info.

Comment: Node detection is fine -- they both get the same server ring. I ended up digging more and saw that dalli uses crc32 as the base hash and spy.net.memcached used md5. Will try to fix and if I do, will report back.